# How to access the Emoji keybaord on a new Samsung Galaxy S22+?

Tags: samsung, keyboard, samsung-galaxy-s

I bought a new Samsung Galaxy S22+, but I don't see the Emoji keyboard. I think it should exist on my phone, but I don't see anywhere how to access it.

My input method is 'Samsung Keyboard', and under 'Languages and types', I have English(US).

**How can I enable it or how to access it?**

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty hidden, but this is the solution:
When the keyboard is open, press long on the comma (',') button to the left of the space bar. Then, you'll have the option to choose different keys, one of which is the emoji symbol, **press it**.

Then, the emoji symbol key will replace the comma one, and you can use it to open the Emoji keyboard.